# Remove or trim any number from the line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simple number 123456

How do I remove the third number so it become

12456

My query

```
 SELECT RIGHT(zip, LEN(zip) - 1) AS MyTrimmedColumn from table1 where Zip ='123456'
```

not working correct.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work using string functions available most databases.

```
declare @n varchar(10)='123456', @pos int=3
select Left(@n,@pos-1) + Right(@n,Len(@n)-@pos)
```

You can also use

```
select Stuff(@n,@pos,1,'')
```

Comment: If I have table1 with zip field '123456'. without declare then how do I write query?

Comment: `Declare` was just to make it work dynamically with any position - you can just hard-code the value directly though - `select stuff(zip,3,1,'') from table`

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stuff to do so.

```
select STUFF(zip, 3, 1, '') AS MyTrimmedColumn from table1 where Zip ='123456'
```

DB-Fiddle:

Query:

```
 select STUFF('123456', 3, 1, '') as MyTrimmedColumn
```

Output:

| MyTrimmedColumn |
| --- |
| 12456 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b254c4af231946423c708c5173f3a2c5)*

Comment: I think `stuff()` would be the preferred solution.